# 'str' object is not callable when trying to prefill form

Tags: flask, wtforms

I'm trying to implement a form that is used to update information that has previously been posted by a user. Unfortunately, I am getting a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

I was looking for solutions online but could not find any - my guess is that the error has something to do with the fact that I am trying to prefill the value of a Select Field but I might be wrong.

### views.py

```
@users.route('/<int:query_id>/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update_query(query_id):
   query = Model.query.get_or_404(query_id)

   if query.author != current_user:
    abort(403)

   form = QueryForm()

   if form.validate_on_submit():
       query.property_type = form.property_type.data
       query.property_type_details = form.property_type_details.data

       db.session.commit()

       return redirect(url_for('users.user_profile', username=current_user.username))

   elif request.method == 'GET':
       form.property_type = query.property_type
       form.property_type_details = query.property_type_details

   return render_template('users/update-query.html', form=form)
```

### forms.py

```
class QueryForm(FlaskForm):
   submit = SubmitField('Send')

   property_type = SelectField(u'Type', choices=[('House', 'House'), ('Apartment', 'Apartment')])
   property_type_details = SelectField(u'Detail', choices=[('Something', 'Something'),('SomethingElse', 'SomethingElse')])
```

### template

```
<form method='POST' class="query-form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{form.hidden_tag()}}

       <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>

          <div class="form-row">
             <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                {{form.property_type.label}}
                {{form.property_type(class="form-control")}} 
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                {{form.property_type_details.label}}
                {{form.property_type_details(class="form-control")}}
              </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

### Most recent call and error

```
File "/Users/1/Desktop/Code/Project/Name/main/templates/users/update-query.html", line 33, in block "content"
{{form.property_type_details(class="form-control")}}

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-filling both form fields means setting the `data` attribute for both field instances. <sup>[1](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.data)</sup>

Currently, instances of both fields are overridden by values retrieved from the database.

The block pre-filling both fields when updated as below addresses errors with rendering both fields pre-filled in the template.

```
elif request.method == 'GET':
       form.property_type.data = query.property_type
       form.property_type_details.data = query.property_type_details
```